# Show img from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-5, crud, laravel-backpack

I can now upload JPG ifrom my BackpackForLaravel to AWS 3 Yahhh!!!

But how or where can i make change this code:

```
 $this->crud->addField([   // image
                    'label' => "Produkt foto",
                    'name' => "productfoto",
                    'type' => 'image',
                    'tab' => 'Produktfoto',
                    'upload' => true,
                    'crop' => true, 
                    'aspect_ratio' => 1,  
                    'disks' => 's3images' // This is not working ??

                ]);
```

To s**howing url from AWS S3** mith my uploaded JPG... (instead of local public)

I can't find any documentation or code examples of it :-(

Please help...

Comment: Is your problem in getting the url of uploaded file?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for how or where I can setup the URL:
'photos' => 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/photos.MYAWS.dk/',
I can only get the local one  http:// mitDomain.com/public/imageDir

Comment: After uploading the image, since you no the absolute path from s3 and the image name, you can construct the http url for the file

Comment: Yes, I have it all (Url to Aws) but can not figure out where I need to integrate it in backpack?

Comment: Did you configure the s3 bucket access control to allow it to access publically? Try to view the file in the bucket then you will get the fullurl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know how this can be of help to you. Pictures to S3 usually need to be base64 encoded so you will need to decode them before you can store in your s3 bucket. So how i handled it sometime ago is this:

```
    $getId = $request->get('myId');
    $encoded_data = $request->get('myphotodata');
    $binary_data = base64_decode($encoded_data);
    $filename_path = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpg"; 
    $directory = 'uploads';
    Storage::disk('s3')->put($directory.'/'.$filename_path , $binary_data);
```

In summary, i am asuming you have the right permission on your bucket and ready to put in image from your storage disks.

Comment: Thanks.. now i have something to work with.. Many Thanks!